# One to many partial association

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have an association called **Includes** between **Parkings** and **Cars**.

This is a one-to-many association that is partial both sides, because a parking can contain zero or more cars and a car can be contained by zero or one parking.

I'd add a `FOREIGN KEY` related to a parking in the Cars table, but it's not true that a car is always inside a parking.

How can this situation be managed?

Comment: Leave the FK `NULL` when a car doesn't belong to a parking.

Comment: What about the guy who parks so sloppily that he takes up two spaces?

Comment: This is a FAQ: there's about a gazillion texts how to deal with 'missing information'. I said 'missing' because that's the usual term, but it's misleading: an empty `lot` does not mean any `car` is missing; a `car` not currently in a `lot` does not mean that car is missing from any particular `lot`. So in this case I'd rather say 'not applicable' or 'not given'; in other examples you might say 'unknown'.

Comment: AntC and I seem to have a different understanding of the model.  Is this about cars and parking lots?  Give a short dataset that exemplifies at least the valid cases of 1:many, missing, zero, zero on the other side, etc.

Comment: I'm going to resist the invitation in @RickJames comment to his answer: StackOverflow does not need more answers to what is a very common 'problem'. Not a problem: a entirely everyday set of database design requirements. Search SO for 'missing information' and/or 'avoid NULLS'. Here's some starters, which include more links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208459/how-should-missing-information-in-relational-databases-be-modeled-properly  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079885/options-for-eliminating-nullable-columns-from-a-db-model-in-order-to-avoid-sql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336687/how-can-i-avoid-nulls-in-my-database-while-also-representing-missing-data

Answer (score -1):

So, the car has a column saying where it is currently parked.  Or `NULL` if it is roaming the roads?

And the parking lot (car park) can have lots of cars?  But it needs no column(s) to indicate such.  The information can be had by a `JOIN` with the other table.

A `FOREIGN KEY` is 2 things:

- An integrity check.  You wan't want a `car` parked in a nonexistent `lot`.
- An `INDEX` to make the above `JOIN` more efficient.

We can't judge the indexes needed without seeing the `SELECTs` (and other queries).

To find all the cars in one lot:

```
SELECT *
    FROM cars
    WHERE lot = 123
```

That needs `INDEX(lot)` (or the FK) in `cars`.

To find where one car is:

```
SELECT lot FROM cars WHERE id = 456;
```

Presumable `cars` has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`.

Comment: There's a need for two integrity checks: no `car` in a nonexistent `lot`, as you have; no more than one `car` in any `lot`, that needs a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `cars.lot` column. `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE lot = 123` should return at most one row: that arises from the structure of the business situation, it's nothing to do with efficiency of indexing.

Comment: In general, a `FOREIGN KEY` that's nullable is problematic (any `JOIN` from Null to the `REFERENCE`d table will fail); a `UNIQUE` constraint on a nullable column is problematic (if there's two Nulls, do they count as unique?). So I would not do this with an extra (nullable) column on `car`; I would make a separate linking table.

Comment: @AntC - Spell all that out, and more, in an Answer.